# Nifi invoke http how to get a value and add as Header during post data

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a NiFi flow which needs to post the data to some other server, before posting it needs to fetch a value from my internal server or Nifi Distributed cache.

And add that Value in to Http header before posting the data, also update when gets particular error code 401.

Below is the flow I am trying, all green processor I could do but stuck at getting the value and adding in invoke http header  . What are other process I can make us to achieve this .

[image: MyNififlow]

Answer (score 0):

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.9.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.InvokeHTTP/

according to documentation on http code 401 `InvikeHTTP` routes file to `No Retry` relation.

also flow file should contain some response attributes including `invokehttp.status.code`

so, you could use `RouteOnAttribute` processor to redirect flow file to your external token processor only when `invokehttp.status.code=401`.

Comment: okay, but how to add the new Header Authorization:Token to invoke http Process

Comment: in documentation check the dynamic properties section. InvikeHTTP properties just press `+` and add the parameter with name `Authorization` and with required value

Comment: Just as a property, that will be included in the headers.